# Reasoning for deductive inference?

Tags: argumentation, deduction, inference

I got a quiz today in my classroom. I need to say True or False to the following:

1. Deductive inferences are typically based on unfounded assumptions.
2. For the valid deductive inference, the conclusion must be true if the premises are true.
3. Deductive inferences rearrange current knowledge in such a way that they merely explicate what we already know.
4. Deductive inferences go beyond information we already have, thus they amplify our knowledge when they are used.

---

My answers were:

1. False
2. False
3. True
4. False

---

Am I wrong?

I think 4 is True, but I am unsure. Please confirm!

Comment: 2. is True; see [validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)).

Comment: 3 and 4 are alternatives, but they are highly debated in philosophy. The traditional view that deductive inference is "knowledge uninformative" was due to Kant but was later rejected by others.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so much for the clarification

Comment: You never mentioned what type of class the quiz is being given. I mention this because oftentimes the terminology used in one class may differ elsewhere. 1 is false. Assumptions are not absolutely necessary in deductive reasoning. I can reason without any assumptions. In Mathematical logic this is different. You will find their first move is usually  to assume something. But this is why you must be clear on what type of logic you are using. 2 is the standard definition of validity but as written is horrible. This doesn't spell out the relationship of premise to each other &   the conclusion.

Comment: The premises should have a relationship between themselves & both should be related to the conclusion.  This refers to the form or pattern the premises  must be in to be valid. As written the sentence makes it seem any old premises will work & magic happens to make it valid or invalid. The form of arguement matters.  3 is false because if we use premises that we know to be true we can extract truth of things we were not aware of & thus learn something new. In Mathematical logic you might hear that phrase but this is not true elsewhere which is why the statement is false. 4 is not clear as is.

Comment: @Logikal My background is electrical engineering. This course is offered as a subject within Philosophy of science. So, I am not deep into it and try to get the top level of understanding from this course.

Comment: The topic which department is doing the teaching is important.  As I stated some terminology will likely be off.  Some times you will see the same words being used differently & this typically leads to confusion. Terms like truth, validity, contraposition an so on can be used differently in context.  Usually the lecturers sound as if what they are telling you is the gospel and there is only this way.  Usually that approach is wrong & you find out later where what you were taught failed when applied or couldn't apply.

Comment: @Logikal I can imagine. This course is taught by the philosophy department, but to nearly all the disciplines (e.g. engineering department, social science, humanity, physics).

Comment: What that generally means is the type of logic you are learning is Mathematical logic as opposed to other types of logic. Many faculty in mathematics teach the logic courses even under the philosophy department. Philosophy can teach some terms differently than the science and math faculty. Again this is not universal knowledge as though they will speak that way. You cant say logic is logic-- it is  all the same thing. All topics use deductive reasoning. So in Rhetoric they may define some terms or use terms differently. In English they may use some common terms differently, etc.

Comment: This is your second question about class work. May I ask what textbook you are using?

Comment: @MarkAndrews The professor is handing out his lecture own notes.